# Images not loading on simulator and physical device flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an app and I ran it on my physical device but the images are not showing up and instead showing up as unable to load _.png. When I run this on the automatic Google Crome tab the images show up perfectly fine. Why would this be?

Comment: Are those local assets or URLs? Does your device have an internet connection? When you enter the image URL in the browser on the device, what happens? If it's local assets, please show your code.

Comment: its just in my assets folder

Comment: Image.asset(
                      min2,
                      scale: 10
                    ),

Answer (score 0):

Oops i forgot to add 'assets/' before the .png file